# Error in CUDA program output

Tags: cuda

Here is my first (plagiarized) CUDA program;

```
  __global__  void vecAdd(float* A, float* B, float* C) 
  { 

      int i = threadIdx.x; 
      A[i]=0; 
      B[i]=i; 
      C[i] = A[i] + B[i]; 
   } 

   #include  <stdio.h> 
   #define  SIZE 10 
    int  main() 
   { 
        int N=SIZE; 
       float A[SIZE], B[SIZE], C[SIZE]; 
       float *devPtrA; 
       float *devPtrB; 
       float *devPtrC; 
       int memsize= SIZE * sizeof(float); 

       cudaMalloc((void**)&devPtrA, memsize); 
       cudaMalloc((void**)&devPtrB, memsize); 
       cudaMalloc((void**)&devPtrC, memsize); 
       cudaMemcpy(devPtrA, A, memsize,  cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
       cudaMemcpy(devPtrB, B, memsize,  cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

       vecAdd<<<1, N>>>(devPtrA,  devPtrB, devPtrC); 
       cudaMemcpy(C, devPtrC, memsize,  cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 

       for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)  
        printf("C[%d]=%f B[%d]=%f\n",i,C[i],i,B[i]); 

        cudaFree(devPtrA); 
       cudaFree(devPtrA); 
       cudaFree(devPtrA); 
   }
```

Here is the output:

erin@ubuntu:~$ nvcc -lcudart vecadd.cu

erin@ubuntu:~$ ./a.out

C[0]=0.000000 B[0]=0.000000

C[1]=0.000000 B[1]=0.000000

C[2]=-0.344699 B[2]=0.000000

C[3]=0.000000 B[3]=0.000000

C[4]=-0.344700 B[4]=0.000000

C[5]=0.000000 B[5]=0.000000

C[6]=0.000000 B[6]=0.000000

C[7]=0.000000 B[7]=0.000000

C[8]=0.000000 B[8]=-0.344690

C[9]=0.000000 B[9]=0.000000
erin@ubuntu:~$

This is on an Ubuntu 64 bit on Pathetic Panda(?) 12.04.

Thanks for any help!

Sincerely,

Erin

---

The expected output should print the value `i` for `B[i]` and `C[i]`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? (hint "help my program doesn't work " isn't really a valid question for stack overflow). The CUDA API has pretty comprehensive error checking, you could start by checking the return value of all of the API calls to see whether there are any errors and then add them to your question. The more information you can provide about your problem, the more likely someone here will be able to help you.

Comment: I am looking at it and I don't see a problem, but when I tried to compile it, I get the same wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your CUDA calls simple do not work at all.
Are you sure everything is installed correctly in your system? Try the following:

Precede your code with:

```
void check() {
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

And put the `check()` after each CUDA call. You may want to automate this somehow in bigger code, but for testing purposes it should suffice. If there is something wrong, you should get a humanly-readable message. In my case I got:

```
CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

I will need to update it ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no cudaMemcpy call to copy back to host array B, you need to add `cudaMemcpy(B, devPtrB, memsize,  cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`.
Then try to replace device code with that

```
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
    __global__  void vecAdd(float* A, float* B, float* C) 

  {     
      int i = threadIdx.x; 
      A[i]=0; 
      B[i]=(float)i; 
      C[i] = (float)(A[i] + B[i]); 
   }
```

The device_launch_parameters.h header contains definition for threadIdx.x call, type casting to float is optional, in my case this code works fine without it.